# How i can get all messages from bot in my BD?

Tags: aiogram

I  record all user responses in a database using middleware:

```
class Add_msg_in_DB(BaseMiddleware):
    async def call(
        self,
        handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, dict[str, any]], Awaitable[any]],
        event: TelegramObject,
        data: dict[str, any]
    ) -> any:
        if isinstance(event, Message):
            user_id =  event.from_user.id
            msg_id = event.message_id
            text = event.text
            username = event.from_user.full_name
            create_new_msg(user_id, msg_id, text, username) 
        result = await handler(event, data)
        return result
```

All messages from users successfully get into my database, but this is not enough for me. I also want to record the messages/responses the bot gave. How can I implement this?

I tried using the on_post_process_message function, thinking that it would intercept any message, both from the user and from the bot - but I was wrong.